# How to change ProgressBar style in ListFragment under compatibility library?

Tags: android, android-fragments

The progress bar is large one by default in `ListFragment`

```
ProgressBar progress = new ProgressBar(context, null, 
            android.R.attr.progressBarStyleLarge);
```

Is the only way to change it using reflection?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this yet?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be able to subclass it and override the `onCreate()` with your custom layout. I haven't done it with the `ProgressBar`, but that's how I customized the `ProgressDialog`.